# Use of uninitialized value in perl

Tags: regex, perl

So I have this code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @arr = ("stuff (06:13)", "more stuff (02:59)", "extra stuff (00:00)");
my @new_arr = map { /\((\d+:\d+)\)/ ; $1 } @arr;
my ( $sum, $hrs, $mins );
$sum = 0;
for my $t (@new_arr) {
my ( $h, $m ) = split m/:/, $t;
my $hm = $h * 3600;
my $tm = $m * 60;
$sum = $sum + $hm + $tm;
}
$mins = sprintf( "%02d", ( $sum % 3600 ) / 60 );
$hrs  = int( $sum / 3600 );
print "$hrs:$mins\n";
```

and I got uninitialized value error

```
   Use of uninitialized value $t in split at DR/Hello World/test.pl line 14.
    Use of uninitialized value $h in multiplication (*) at DR/test.pl line 16.
    Use of uninitialized value $m in multiplication (*) at DR/test.pl line 17.
```

so how can I fix that?

Comment: Always always always check the result of a match.  In this case you got `undef`s you didn't want.  In other cases, you might have gotten the previous value of `$1` and had no warnings at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`stuff (3+06:13)` doesn't match `/\((\d+:\d+)\)/`, so `$1` is left untouched, so `$1` contains undef, so `undef` ends up in `@arr`.

It's unwise to use `$1` without making sure the pattern matches. Either adjust the pattern to make sure it always matches,

```
/\(([\d+]+:\d+)\)/
```

Or filter out the results that don't match.

```
my @new_arr = map { /\((\d+:\d+)\)/ ? $1 : () } @arr;
  -or-
my @new_arr = map { /\((\d+:\d+)\)/ } @arr;
```

You have a similar problem with `map { /\((\d+\++)/ ; $1 }`.

Answer (score 3):

```
You're missing a capture in two of your regexes.
```

Your first one:

```
my @new_arr = map { /\((\d+:\d+)\)/ ; $1 } @arr;
```

Misses a capture in the first instance:

```
$VAR2 = [
          undef,
          '02:59',
          '00:00'
        ];
```

Which can be corrected (see below).

Your second capture also fails to capture anything:

```
my @x = map {/\((\d+\++)/ ; $1 } @arr;
```

See:

```
$VAR3 = [
          '3+',
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

This is because your asking it to find a digit `\d` followed by a literal `+` one or more times, which only occurs in `$arr[0]`. Below i've adjusted to capture `0` if no capture is found:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = ("stuff (3+06:13)", "more stuff (02:59)", "extra stuff (00:00)");
my @new_arr = map { /\(.*?(\d+:\d+)\)/ ; $1 } @arr;
my @x = map {/\((\d+\+)|(0)/ ; $1 // $2 } @arr;
my ( $sum, $hrs, $mins );
$sum = 0;
for my $t (@new_arr) {
my ( $h, $m ) = split m/:/, $t;
my $hm = $h * 3600;
my $tm = $m * 60;
$sum = $sum + $hm + $tm;
}
$mins = sprintf( "%02d", ( $sum % 3600 ) / 60 );
$hrs  = int( $sum / 3600 );
print "$hrs:$mins\n";

print Dumper (\@arr, \@new_arr, \@x);


$VAR1 = [
          'stuff (3+06:13)',
          'more stuff (02:59)',
          'extra stuff (00:00)'
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          '06:13',
          '02:59',
          '00:00'
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          '3+',
          '0',
          '0'
        ];
```

Output:

```
9:12
```

Comment: `(...)` is a capture. It's not missing. I didn't say what you said I said.

Comment: sorry I used the wrong code, and I fixed it, but I still do have the same problem